# Show DIVs when page loads, not just 'on change' of drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have sections of a form which display based on the selection of a drop down list:

```
$('#Selection').on('change', function () {

if(this.value === "Section1"){
    $("#Section1").show();
} else {
    $("#Section1").hide();
}

  if(this.value === "Section2"){
    $("#Section2").show();
} else {
    $("#Section2").hide();
}

  if(this.value === "Section3"){
    $("#Section3").show();
} else {
    $("#Section3").hide();
}

  if(this.value === "Section4"){
    $("#Section4").show();
} else {
    $("#Section4").hide();
}

      if(this.value === "Section5"){
    $("#Section5").show();
} else {
    $("#Section5").hide();
}
```

});

This works well for my 'Add' function because the default drop down list selection is 'Please Select...' which means there is a 'change' which triggers my function.

For my 'Edit' function, a selection has already been made, and it's unlikely a change to this selection will be made. I've tried to change the .on('change') bit to .on('load') but that doesn't seem to work!

It feels like there is a simple change I need to make, but I'm rubbish at javaScript!

Thanks.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it that what you want to achieve ?

Comment: on document.ready do $("#Selection").trigger("change") to trigger your code manually :)

Comment: you can set a function like this `<body onload="callmyshowhidefunction">`

Comment: Just a side note – `this.value` could be used as `ID` selector..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to trigger your code manually on document ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Selection").trigger("change");
});
```

If you are happy with the functionality inside your change handler;

Comment: I don't understand how to use this?

Comment: @zerohero Why don't you use this website to help programmers with difficulties and problems, or to help solve your own difficulties and problems; I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @blackers keep your original code as it is and add $("#Selection").trigger("change") inside your document.ready.
This will then be used to invoke your code, cause in your code, you are trying to listen for change events on $("#Selection"). Essentially, you will be triggering the event with code.

Comment: Thanks I understand the logic of how this should work now. Nothing seems to happen when I add this though, could this be because I have to search for a record after the page is loaded? This then loads the page with data so I doubt it. Sorry for being a pain :D

Comment: When you add this code, then try to debug your event handler and see what this.value is. 
It may be that this.value doesn't equal any of the things you are expecting it to equal. I don't have your html to be able to help you more effectively

Comment: @zerohero I'm a student! I've done Java in programming, and HTML, CSS, PHP, in Web Technology Integration, I haven't really done much on JavaScript but am trying to utilize it so I can make better web apps! First I've got to learn it. My original code took me a long time and it does most of what I'm after, I've been stumped on this bit for a while which is why I've asked the community. Don't be so rude and don't make assumptions.

Comment: @blackers if you could give me a jsfiddle with the relevant piece of your html and javascript, I could help you more.
Go to jsfiddle.net, write he code, hit "Update" at the top menu and send me the url and I can help you.

Comment: @klikas https://jsfiddle.net/og5quxnm/27/ Here is the J Fiddle I don't know what is missing but it's not working as it is on my side. This is pretty much how I have it now, but it shows the DIVs when you make a selection. I'm trying to make it show the DIVs when a selection has already been made, i.e. afteryou search for a record

Comment: @blackers ok check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/og5quxnm/30/

This shows you the concept I described in my answer.

Please note that in this jsfiddle, <option value="Section2" selected> Section2</option> has the "selected" attribute on load of the page, as I am assuming you do when you first render your page from the server-side.

Comment: YES!! This is exactly what I was having difficulty with! Lol if i was a more adept programmer I would have understood your OP. Thanks for the help and explanations, really useful!

Comment: glad you got that sorted @blackers :)

Comment: @zerohero [be-nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and SE comment FAQ [Etiquette for posting civil and informative comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138173/etiquette-for-posting-civil-and-informative-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("#Section1").show();
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to put an IF in this? I only want Section1 to be displayed if  it has been selected previously.

Comment: @blackers want us to do your work for you or can you spend 2 seconds researching what you want to do and code it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I think **Klikas** solution is the correct one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#Selection').value!=""){$('#Selection').trigger("change");}
});
```

You can simplify your long function with something like this:

```
$('#Selection').on('change', function(){
    var p=["Section1", "Section2", "Section3", "Section4", "Section5"];
    for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++){var n=p[i]; var t=$("#"+n); if(t){this.value===n?t.show():t.hide();}}
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code with this version but it seems to be working the same as before. With my previous code, and this simplified code, when I search for a record and 'Section1'  appears in the drop down list (As this was selected when the record was created). At this point I need Section1 to be visible, at the moment I have to Select 'Section2' to display that, then select back to 'Section1' to view the data in that section.

Comment: you will have to be more clear.... post more code.... based on what you posted and how you explained it is very difficult for me to figure out what exactly is it that you need ....try to understand...